# How to plot this equation in MATLAB? Keep getting matrix dimension errors

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, equation

The code I have is:

```
T=[0:0.1:24];
omega=((12-T)/24)*360;
alpha = [0:1:90];
latitude=35;
delta=[-23.45:5:23.45];
sind(alpha)=sind(delta).*sind(latitude)+cosd(delta).*cosd(latitude).*cosd(omega)
cosd(phi)=(sind(alpha).*sind(latitude)-cosd(delta))./(cosd(alpha).*cosd(latitude))
```

alpha represents my y-axis and is an angle between 0 and 90 degrees. phi represents my x-axis and is an angle between say -120 to +120. The overall result should look something like a half sine-wave.

Whenever I try to input that last line I get the error stating inner matrix dimensions must agree. So I tried to use reshape on my matrices for those variables I defined so that they work. But then I get '??? ??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.'

It seems very tedious to have to reshape my matrix every time I define a new set of variables in order to use them with an equation. Those variables are used for defining my axis range, is there a better way I can lay them out or an automatic command that will make sure they work every time?

I want to plot alpha and phi as a graph using something like

```
plot(alpha,phi)
```

but can't get past those errors? can't I just use a command that says something like define x-axis [0:90], define y-axis [-120:120] or something? I have spent far too much time on this problem and can't find a solution. I just want to plot the graph. Somebody please help! thanks.

Thanks

Comment: There is something fundamentally wrong with the commands `sind(alpha) = *stuff*` and `cosd(phi) = *stuff*`. The terms on the left of the `=` sign are not something that you can assign a value to. Also, you are trying to do element-wise multiplaction of things that are many different sizes, which is not allowed. Perhaps it would help if you posted some math or pseudocode to explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to plot a sun path diagram which is basically a chart showing the path of the sun throughout the year.

The chart has two axes. The y-axis is represented by the solar altitude angle (alpha), the x-axis is represented by the solar azimuth angle (phi)

The equations are:

sin alpha = sin(delta)*sin(L) + cos(delta)*cos(L)*cos(omega) - solar altitude equation

cos(phi) = sin(alpha)*sin(L)-sin(delta) / (cos(alpha)*cos(L))

Where L is the latitude of the location (can be considered a constant value).

omega is the hour angle and is defined as omega = ((12-T)/24 *360)

where T is time

Comment: The chart looks like this:

http://solardat.uoregon.edu/download/temp/37340782.pdf

I've basically just tried to assign reasonable ranges to those variables such as T (0-24 as in 24 hours), omega etc and then define the equations so that I can plot them. That's ALL I want to do. I've been trying to do this for 2 days and it's very frustrating.

This link also explains the math in a better format: http://www.pvresources.com/siteanalysis.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start for you:

```
% Latitude
L=35;

% Hour Angle
h = [-12:5/60:12];
w = 15*h;

% Initialize and clear plot window
figure(1); clf;

% Plot one day per month for half of the year
for N = 1:30:365/2
    % Declination
    d = 23.45*sind(360*(284+N)/365);

    % Sun Height
    alpha = asind(sind(L)*sind(d) + cosd(L)*cosd(d)*cosd(w));

    % Solar Azimuth 
    x = ( sind(alpha)*sind(L)-sind(d) )./( cosd(alpha)*cosd(L) );
    y = cosd(d)*sind(w)./cosd(alpha);
    phi = real(atan2d(y,x));

    % Plot
    plot(phi,alpha); hold on;
end

hold off;
grid on;
axis([-180, 180, 0, 90]);
xlabel('Solar Azimuth')
ylabel('Solar Elevation')
```

The function `asind` is inherently limited to return values in the range of -90 to 90.  That means that you will not get a plot that spans over 240 degrees like the one you linked to.  In order for the plot to not have the inflection at +/- 90 degrees, you will need to find a way to infer the quadrant. Update: I added the cosine term to get an angle using `atan2d`.
[image: Matlab Plot]

Hopefully this will be enough to give you an idea of how to use Matlab to get the kind of result that you are after.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and detail. Your answer has been most helpful. The plot does look strange because asind doesn't have the full value range. Nevertheless I will run through this script and learn from the syntax and see if I can get the proper plot. Very much appreciated! Regards.

Comment: The best way to correct for the discrepancy would be to find an expression for the cosine of the azimuth angle as well. Then you can use the sin and cos values in `atan2d`, which maps to `[-180,180]` like you are looking for.

Comment: +1 for effort even though this solution is very inefficient (I assume you're looping with `hold on` just for demonstrative purposes).

Comment: @chappjc:  The main purpose of this code is readability and modifiability.  Not all code needs to be optimized. `>> tic; solar_plot; toc; Elapsed time is 0.023685 seconds.` How many clock cycles am I really going to save?

Comment: Not much in this example, that's true.  I'm not criticizing, just pointing out that plotting a single point inside a loop is not great practice.  The OP is just learning MATLAB, so it seems appropriate to point this out so in future problems he doesn't run into performance problems and wonder why.  Like I said, I upvoted because your answer was helpful and correct, but a little constructive feedback is not a bad thing I think.  :)

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the script.  `phi` and `alpha` are vectors.  The loop *only executes 7 times*, once for each of the seven curves. If you thought I was plotting one point at a time, I can see why you thought the script was "very inefficient."  :)

Comment: I changed the equation for the solar Azimuth using an eqn in cos from a textbook which I have. 


    % Solar Azimuth 
    phi = acosd((sind(alpha)*sind(L)-sind(d))./(cosd(alpha)*cosd(L)));

This plots the curve correctly BUT matlab states :

    Warning: Imaginary parts of complex X and/or Y arguments ignored 

If you have any additional time to explain why this is happening and how I can correct it to get the full curve? here is a pic:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/104069213/curve.png

@chappjc if you have an alternative feel free to suggest, may be useful in future

Comment: Short answer: If `x>1` then `acosd(x)` is complex.  Long Answer: When `sin` and `cos` are functions that map the real numbers to the range `[-1,1]`, any numbers outside that range are not in the domain of the inverse `sin` and `cos` functions.  But we can "extend" our definition such that `sin` and `cos` map the complex plane to the complex plane, and then the function becomes invertible.

Comment: @nispio Apologies but it appears I don't have enough reputation to use the chat rooms if you wouldn't mind taking additional questions here.

How can I make it invertible as MATLAB syntax as a complex variable? I've tried running my own script but it didn't work or make sense. 

Thanks.

Comment: Updated post to incorporate the new cosine term.

Comment: MATLAB returns: ??? Undefined function or method 'atan2d' for input arguments of type 'double' when I try to run the new script..

Also, the solar elevation should not be a negative I don't think (from 0-90) but I will try to figure that out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Element-wise multiplication (`.*`) and division `./`, not the matrix versions:

```
sind(alpha)=sind(delta).*sind(latitude)+cosd(delta).*cosd(latitude).*cosd(omega)
cosd(phi)=(sind(alpha).*sind(latitude)-cosd(delta))./(cosd(alpha).*cosd(latitude))
```

But a bigger problem is that you can't index with decimal or non-positive values.  Go back to the code before you got the subscript indices error.  The indices "must either be real **positive** integers or logicals".

Comment: Okay so removing the . I did this for one equation and got the same answer. I may not even be using the correct method. I just want to plot the graph of these equations. I do not care about the values stored within the matrix as long it plots the right range.



 T=[0:1:4];
omega=((12-T)/24)*360;
alpha = [0:1:4];
latitude=35;
delta=[0:1:4];

>>  sind(alpha)=sind(delta)*sind(latitude)+cosd(delta)*cosd(latitude)*cosd(omega)



??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. In my original code I had ./ but forgot to paste it correctly (will edit that now). THAT gives me the subscript indices error and without . and having just * or / gives me the matrix dimension error.

Comment: As the error message says, `Subscript indices must either be real **positive** integers or logicals`.  Your `T` index starts at `0`.

Comment: But I need it to start from 0 because its the 0 on the axis. Same with the other values. So how is this possible?! Apologies, I'm very new to MATLAB. How can I plot these equations with a similar sort of number range?

Comment: Use another variable for indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a bit confused about MATLAB sintax (as nispio mentioned). Maybe you want to do something like this?

```
T=[0:0.1:24];
omega=((12-T)/24)*360;
alpha = [0:1:90];
latitude=35;
delta=[-23.45:5:23.45];
[o1,d1]=meshgrid(omega,delta);
[a2,d2]=meshgrid(alpha,delta);
var1=sind(d1(:)).*sind(latitude)+cosd(d1(:)).*cosd(latitude).*cosd(o1(:));
var2=(sind(a2(:)).*sind(latitude)-cosd(d2(:)))./(cosd(a2(:)).*cosd(latitude));
plot(var1);hold on;plot(var2);
```

If not, you should post the algorithm or pseudocode

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will accept nispio's answer. Appreciate your help!